# Already explicitly convert NSArray into [AnyObject] but still get the error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

Hi I just updated my xcode to the newest version(7.1.1 i think), then I got the error saying `NSArray` is not implicitly convertible to AnyObject, from this line:  `self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction:.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`

viewControllers is a `NSArray` type. It suggests me to use "AS" to explicitly convert. However, I think I already did that. Why am I still getting the error? Is it formatting issue? Thanks!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var pageTitles: NSArray!
var pageImages: NSArray!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.pageTitles = NSArray(objects: "hi","hey")
    self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "1","2")
    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController")as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
    var viewControllers = NSArray(object:startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction:.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)


    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height-60)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `NSArray` at all? You could just use native Swift arrays.

Comment: I just start learning swift and i did this following a tutorial. So i just want to fix the problem I asked @Pascal My old version xcode didn't give me this array do you have any idea why?

Comment: Instead of doing `NSArray(object: "hi")` do `["hi"]`.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` is declared as `[UIViewController]?` rather than `[AnyObject]?`.

Probably this is sufficient:

```
let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([startVC], direction:.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```